# Oшибка "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2255 и как её исправить?

Tags: python, django

При запуске Django сервера и выполнения каких-то действий в логах всплывает ошибка

> "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2255

Можете подсказать, из-за чего она возникает, и как её исправить?

Comment: Сама по себе она ничего в работе не портит, но её наличие настораживает

Comment: Все современные браузеры запрашивают эту иконку, что бы отобразить ее на вкладке с вашей страницей. Можете создать такую, и тогда ошибок не будет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`favicon.ico` - это обычно значок сайта во вкладках браузера и при открытии страницы его браузер его пытается запросить (дефолтно).

Добавьте в `<head>` блок вашей страницы следующее:

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,=">
```

Либо вы можете убрать из логов nginx'а:

```
# skip favicon.ico
#
location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    return 204;
}
```

[Такой-же вопрос на английском с развернутым ответом.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests)

Comment: Только скорее 404, чем 204, ведь успешно вернуть данные не представляется возможным, а `GET` именно что получает данные. См. [MDN про 204](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204).